# Transform Array to Output in Certain Manner

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

**PHP**

```
    <?php 
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    print_r($result); //or var_dump($result); for more info
    foreach($result as $row){
        $half = array_splice($row,0,5);
        echo implode(" ",$half)."<br /><br />Merchant Offered:<br />".implode(" ",$row);
    }   
    ?>
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT uFName, uLName, listTitle, listPropPrice, listCmt, listDt, mFName, mLName, moAmt, moDtOff
FROM User U, Listing L, Merchant M, MerchantOffer MO
WHERE U.uID = L.uID
and L.listID = MO.listID
and M.mID = MO.mId
```

**Currently outputting:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAtcf.png

How do I get it to **NOT** output the first big array :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Joseph [1] => Dickinson [2] => Need Xbox 360 [3] => 150 [4] => I need one quick! [5] => 2011-09-15 [6] => John [7] => Doe [8] => 149.99 [9] => 2011-09-15 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Joseph [1] => Dickinson [2] => Need Xbox 360 [3] => 150 [4] => I need one quick! [5] => 2011-09-15 [6] => Jane [7] => Doe [8] => 154.99 [9] => 2011-09-15 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Joseph [1] => Dickinson [2] => Need Xbox 360 [3] => 150 [4] => I need one quick! [5] => 2011-09-15 [6] => Diana [7] => Matthews [8] => 160.00 [9] => 2011-09-15 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Joseph [1] => Dickinson [2] => Need Xbox 360 [3] => 150 [4] => I need one quick! [5] => 2011-09-15 [6] => Amanda [7] => Koste [8] => 174.99 [9] => 2011-09-15 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Warren [1] => Kennan [2] => Need New Sofa [3] => 1000 [4] => Need one quick [5] => 2011-09-15 [6] => Diana [7] => Matthews [8] => 495.99 [9] => 2011-09-15 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => Warren [1] => Kennan [2] => Need New Sofa [3] => 1000 [4] => Need one quick [5] => 2011-09-15 [6] => Amanda [7] => Koste [8] => 489.99 [9] => 2011-09-15 ) ) Joseph Dickinson Need Xbox 360 150 I need one quick!
```

and instead **TO POST** the output like:

```
Joseph Dickinson Need Xbox 360 150 I need one quick!
Merchant Offered:
2011-09-15 John Doe 149.99 2011-09-15
```

Thanks

Comment: You're fetching the entirety of the query's results, then splice out the first 5 rows and dumping out the entirety of those rows.

Comment: I fixed the huge entirety being outputted. How can I change the output to match the above **TO POST**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

**The code**

```
 <?php
    ...
    // Do a loop on each row of your result / repeat the display
    foreach ($result as $row) {
         for ($i=0;$i<=count($row); $i++) {
               echo $row[$i].' ';
               if ($i==6) {
                   echo '<br/><br/>Merchant Offered:<br/>';
               }
         }
         echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
```

**Output would be**

```
 Joseph Dickinson Need Xbox 360 150 I need one quick!
 Merchant Offered:
 2011-09-15 John Doe 149.99 2011-09-15

 Joseph Dickinson Need Xbox 360 150 I need one quick!
 Merchant Offered:
 2011-09-15 Jane Doe 149.99 2011-09-15
 ...
```

**Two stuff:**

- Not sure output would be exactly what you need, do you really want to repeat the user request on each line or do you want one time and after all merchantoffer? like below

  ```
  Joseph Dickinson Need Xbox 360 150 I need one quick!
  Merchant Offered:
  2011-09-15 John Doe 149.99 2011-09-15
  2011-09-15 Jane Doe 149.99 2011-09-15
  ...
  ```

  In that case you need to add an identifier on people request to group the line for example...
- Maybe you can concatenate your informations into your sql statement to improve the readability of your code and avoid the line : if ($i==6) which doesn't really represents something understandable.